# IIS serving static files despite my attempts to stop it

Tags: c#, iis, owin, static-files

So, I've been working on project that's making use of the Katana/Owin pipeline. And I'm trying to use Owin to serve static files securely. Now, when I run the project locally through VS, everything works perfectly fine.

However, when I deploy it to a server (Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7), IIS has decided that it'll be damned before it lets any dirty managed handler manage its static files. Even when I've removed the static file handler. Even when I've added my own handler for a specific path. Even when I've told it to run All Managed Modules For All Requests. And since the path that's being passed in is a virtual path, IIS of course craps out and dies and either spits out a 500 or a 404 error. I'm not entirely sure what causes it to spit out a 500 over a 404, but anytime the request is deeper than 1 directory deep it gives out a 500 over 404. (/Client/Content/Folder/static.html(404) vs /Client/Content/Folder/SubFolder/static.html (500))

I'm just not sure where to go from here, at all. Worse still, when I've deployed to my local IIS (not running it out of VS, that is.) it works perfectly. It respects the web.config, the Owin middleware handles the static requests perfectly, the security is in place. Everything is peachy. Granted I'm running IIS 8 express on my box, but I'm not convinced that that is it.

Comment: have you checked all the IIS settings for differences between your local version and the server, such as the app pool, identity settings etc? what error message shows up in the event viewer? have you installed all the necessary asp.net modules through Programs and Features?

Comment: Without a peek on your web.config and/or IIS configuration you just ask every reader to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post my comment as an answer since the more I think about it, the more sure I am that it could be the issue.

Check that all necessary asp.net and IIS features have been installed correctly via Programs and Features - do a comparison between your dev and server environments. I've experienced essentially the same issues as yourself and this was usually the reason.

If this isn't the reason, check the IIS settings/Application pool settings make sure they are the on dev and production environments.

Comment: So, I got a fresh install of IIS and and windows server 2012 (Kind of wanted to reduce to the possible differences between my local and the server by using IIS 8).

I've installed all of the .NET framework, etc etc. Despite all of that, it's still not passing the request through to managed code. And if I remove the static file handler, it just complains about the static file handler. 

I have <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> marked in the web.config. I've experimented with various custom handlers, nothing seems to be working.